# Java nested stream

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

Quick question: 
How do I reference the parent element of a nested stream like this:

```
jpegDir.stream()
    .parallel()
    .map(E -> createDimentionArray(E.getDescription(1), E.getDescription(3)))
    .filter(E -> E != null)
    .forEach(E -> images.stream()
        .filter(J -> J.getType().contains(".jpg"))
        .forEach(I -> I.setSize(E))
    );
```

The parent element E from the last `forEach` is of type `string`. Is there a way for me to reference E inside the `setSize()` method ?

Comment: That should work as is, you're calling `setSize` within the scope of `E`.

Comment: Then it must be some other part of my code that returns a null value..

Comment: You can add `.peek(System.out::println)` calls to your streams to print out the values being processed in the streams...

Comment: Note that the `E` that was used to return the `createDimentionArray(E.getDescription(1), E.getDescription(3))` is not the same `E` as the lambda parameter given to `forEach`. Its type is the return type of `createDimentionArray`. It may be normal, but it's confusing to name different things with the same name.

Comment: Yes, I can see the confusing that the parameter is the same name. But yes, I've figured out that the problem was the second filter, the `.jpg` was returning 0 values, because the type, is actually not with a "." in front.

Comment: Are you aware that the result of the processing of `images.stream() .filter(J -> J.getType().contains(".jpg"))` will always be the same? Repeating that is not only wasting resources, it doesn’t seem to be the right thing as you are calling `setSize` on thesame objects multiple times, for each element of `jpegDir` that passes the filter. Either, that’s far off from the intention, or the naming scheme of your variables and methods is questionable.

Comment: @Holger yes I'm aware of that and I'm in the middle of changing the code to make sense so that i don't set the same size for every object. But thanks for pointing it out

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE**

Just posting the fixed code, so if others have trouble, they can have a look:

```
public class Inderxer {

  public void indexFolder(Path path) throws IOException {
      List<Image> images = new LinkedList<>();
       Files.walk(path).parallel().forEach(E -> {
        if (!E.toFile().isDirectory() && !E.toFile().getName().contains(".DS") && FilenameUtils.getExtension(E.toFile().toString()) != ".kmz") {
            try {

                Metadata metadata = ImageMetadataReader.readMetadata(E.toFile());
                if (FilenameUtils.getExtension(E.toFile().toString()).contains("jpg")) {
                    List<Directory> dirs = metadata.getDirectoriesOfType(JpegDirectory.class).stream().collect(Collectors.toList());
                    images.add(new Image(E.getFileName().toString(), FilenameUtils.getExtension(E.toFile().toString()), dirs));
                } else {
                    List<Directory> dirs = metadata.getDirectoriesOfType(PngDirectory.class).stream().collect(Collectors.toList());
                    images.add(new Image(E.getFileName().toString(), FilenameUtils.getExtension(E.toFile().toString()), dirs));
                }

            } catch (ImageProcessingException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
    images.stream()
            .forEach(M -> M.getDirectory().stream()
                    .forEach(D -> {
                        if (!M.getType().equals("png")) {
                            M.setSize(createDimentionArray(D.getDescription(1), D.getDescription(3), "jpg"));
                        } else {
                            M.setSize(createDimentionArray(D.getDescription(1), D.getDescription(2), "png"));
                        }
                    }));

    images.forEach(System.out::println);
}

private String createDimentionArray(String h, String w, String type) {
    String res = "";
    if (type.equals("jpg")) {
        if (h != null && w != null) {
            String[] hsplit = h.split("pixels");
            String[] wsplit = w.split("pixels");
            if (hsplit[0] != null && wsplit[0] != null) {
                res = hsplit[0]; //Hight
                res += wsplit[0]; //Width
                res += "\n";
            }
            return res;
        } else {
            return null;
        }

    } else {
        if (h != null && w != null) {
            String[] hsplit = h.split("pixels");
            String[] wsplit = w.split("pixels");
            if (hsplit[0] != null && wsplit[0] != null) {
                res = hsplit[0]; //Hight
                res += " ";
                res += wsplit[0]; //Width
                res += "\n";
            }
            return res;
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Just wow. There are so many mistakes in this code. Use `equals` to compare `String`s. Introduce a filtering step in the `Stream` pipeline instead of filtering in `foreach`. Use a `Collector` to create `images`.

Comment: Also, it's not because you are using lambda's you can't extract methods any more, try to write declarative code with intention revealing names and move things to the right abstraction level.

Comment: That's cool and all.. But insted of making rude comments, could you guys make an answer with some examples of how to fix these "mistake"? That way your comments become constructive.. I would not make these "mistakes" if I'd knew the right way of doing it..

Comment: @Lasse Since this is an answer not the question, comments are the right thing to do here. There are several hints in the comments to fix your problems. Maybe you should read some tutorials on `Stream` API ([official Oracle tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/streams/index.html)). Also on the same resource ["How to compare Strings"](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/comparestrings.html). It is not our duty to teach you. If you have a specific question then you'll get a specific answer.